# How are webpages linked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm having trouble figuring out how two pages are linked. For example if I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<button onclick='myfunction()'>Click me</button>
<body>

<script>
function myfunction() {
//some code to take user to the next page
}
</script>

<style>
some style code
</style>
```

How is the code for the second html file called?

Do all the contents of all webpages reside in one big html file where elements are hidden depending on the what they've clicked on? For example - the `div`'s shown on the 'home page' would be shown, while other ones hidden, if you click on a 'home' tab; essentially reformatting the elements on a page for a given file.

Comment: Create pages and link through hyperlinks

Comment: You can do this using JS!

Comment: I assume you mean the <a href='url'> tag, but I don't understand how that works. Is it all one giant file or many html docs where each is called as needed?

Comment: @hac13: No, they are separate files, at different URIs. If you click a link, your browser fetches the new page from the server. You can see your address bar change.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: This is a question in basic web programming and should be studied in a web programming course or in a book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

1) They're typically on different `.html` documents, and are usually loaded with `<a href="http://location">Link text</a>`.
2) You can load a page via javascript by doing `document.location = "http://location"` as well.

Comment: I didn't know it was as simple as that. I just tried it on a notepad and it actually worked. Great!

Comment: [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) has a full documentation on HTML and JavaScript